# pd.concat Plan shapes are not aligned error

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to concat two dataframes that have exactly the same column names.

```
 df1 = [['A','B','C']]
 df1 =     A                  B             C
        1762             53RC982          0.22
        1763             56XY931          0.33
        1767             54AB171          0.47
        1771             38CD410          0.22

 df2 = [['A','B','C']]
         A                    B             C
        1810             53RC982          0.42
        1811             58XY821          0.63
        1812             47AB261          0.33
        1820             38CD410          0.81
```

where A is the unique column. I want to basically join them have the df1 and df2 untouched one after the other this shouldn't be a problem as I have a unique column i.e. if df1 is 100 rows and df2 is 50 rows the combined number of rows should be 150
I've tried:

```
 df_final = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0, sort =True)
```

However, this is giving me

```
ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned
```

if I do :
df_final = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

This gives me the information side by side. I've also tried the

```
.append
```

method similar results.

Comment: Can you show the sample dataframe ?

Comment: @YOBEN_S edited the question to add example

Comment: I try your sample data nothing wrong with it

Comment: may be you have duplicate column names in either of the dataframe

Comment: @anky there are no duplicate columns

Comment: I believe I found the problem even though the columns are same they have different  dtypes. Hence, causing dtypes

Answer (score 0):

The problem this was happening is that the dfs didn't have the same data types. Used

```
 df1['A'] = df1['A'].astype(str)
 df2['A'] = df2['A'].astype(str)
```

then

```
 df_final= pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0, sort = True)
```

to merge them